# Selenium Pagination Error when scraping clutch.co

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, pagination

For some reason this clutch.co scraper isn't clicking the "next" button and navigating to the next page. So when I run this code it'll only get information from the first page and then close itself.

I added in waits to allow the page to load but it hasn't helped. When watching the browser you can see it scrolls to the bottom of the page but then closes itself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

website = "https://clutch.co/us/web-developers"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(website)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
company_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'provider-info')))

#pagination
pagination = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="pagination justify-content-center"]')
pages = pagination.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'li')
last_page = int(250)



company_names = []
taglines = []
locations = []
costs = []
ratings = []

current_page = 1


while current_page <= last_page:
    company_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'provider-info')))

    for company_element in company_elements:
        company_name = company_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "company_info").text
        company_names.append(company_name)


        tagline = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//p[@class="company_info__wrap tagline"]').text
        taglines.append(tagline)

        rating = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//span[@class="rating sg-rating__number"]').text
        ratings.append(rating)

        location = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@class="locality"]').text
        locations.append(location)

        cost = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="list-item block_tag custom_popover"]').text
        costs.append(cost)

    current_page = current_page + 1

    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//li[@class="page-item next"]/a[@class="page-link"]")')
        next_page.click()
        time.sleep(10)
    except:
        break

driver.close()



data = {'Company_Name': company_names, 'Tagline': taglines, 'location': locations, 'Ticket_Price': costs, 'Rating': ratings}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('companies_test1.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: did you get a workaround for the cloudflare-thing!? Would be awesome to know

Comment: Dear Buddy - always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are there. What do you find in your soup?  Plz let us know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is wrong, use:

```
next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//li[@class="page-item next"]/a[@class="page-link"]')
```

But the website block it. If you remove the try/catch, you can read error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
Message: element click intercepted: Element
<a class="page-link" data-page="1" href="/us/web-developers?pag e=1" data-link="?page=1">...</a>
is not clickable at point (622, 888).
Other element would receive the click: 
<div id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtons" style="padding-left: 0px;">...</div>
```

A better code, but my IP/settings require Cloudfare captcha:

```
next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//li[@class="page-item next"]/a[@class="page-link"]')
np = next_page.get_attribute('href')
driver.get(np)
time.sleep(6)
```

Comment: Yeah it works thanks! I also get the Cloudfare captcha I'll find a work around

Comment: The way to thanks here is to vote up/accept the answer. Can you tell me what is the workaround? If you don't want it to be public, you can find my email on the page linked in my profile.

Comment: did you get a workaround for the cloudflare-thing!? Would be awesome to know

Comment: Search github projects

Comment: good day dear Gilles - well could it be that the Google-Colab-Selenium helps here to solve this problem. Afaik it manages the executable and the required Selenium Options for us: cf https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium - look forward to hear from you again. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

well this runs for me.

it seems like sometimes there might be some issue with locating the elements with the class name 'provider-info': i guess that this could be due to changes in the website's structure on the clutch.co-site or on the other handside some timing issues. I think that there a handling of potential exceptions should set in; This one works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import time

website = "https://clutch.co/us/web-developers"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(website)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Function to handle page navigation
def navigate_to_next_page():
    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@class="page-item next"]/a[@class="page-link"]')
        np = next_page.get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(np)
        time.sleep(6)
        return True
    except:
        return False

company_names = []
taglines = []
locations = []
costs = []
ratings = []

current_page = 1
last_page = 250

while current_page <= last_page:
    try:
        company_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'provider-info')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout Exception occurred while waiting for company elements.")
        break

    for company_element in company_elements:
        try:
            company_name = company_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "company_info").text
            company_names.append(company_name)

            tagline = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/p[@class="company_info__wrap tagline"]').text
            taglines.append(tagline)

            rating = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@class="rating sg-rating__number"]').text
            ratings.append(rating)

            location = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@class="locality"]').text
            locations.append(location)

            cost = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="list-item block_tag custom_popover"]').text
            costs.append(cost)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Element not found while extracting company details.")
            continue

    current_page += 1

    if not navigate_to_next_page():
        break

driver.close()

data = {'Company_Name': company_names, 'Tagline': taglines, 'location': locations, 'Ticket_Price': costs, 'Rating': ratings}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('companies_test1.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

which gives back the following

```
  import pandas as pd
Timeout Exception occurred while waiting for company elements.
                    Company_Name  ... Rating
0           Hyperlink InfoSystem  ...    4.9
1             Plego Technologies  ...    5.0
2                  Azuro Digital  ...    4.9
3                     Savas Labs  ...    5.0
4               The Gnar Company  ...    4.8
5            Sunrise Integration  ...    5.0
6             Baytech Consulting  ...    5.0
7                Inventive Works  ...    4.9
8                        Utility  ...    4.8
9                     Busy Human  ...    5.0
10                     Rootstrap  ...    4.8
11                        micro1  ...    4.9
12                  ChopDawg.com  ...    4.8
13             Emergent Software  ...    4.9
14         Beehive Software Inc.  ...    5.0
15                   3 Media Web  ...    4.9
16                     Webstacks  ...    5.0
17                Mutually Human  ...    5.0
18                    AnyforSoft  ...    4.8
19                  NL Softworks  ...    5.0
20  OpenSource Technologies Inc.  ...    4.8
21                Marcel Digital  ...    4.8
22                      Twin Sun  ...    5.0
23          SPARK Business Works  ...    4.9
24                        Darwin  ...    4.9
25                       Perrill  ...    5.0
26                          Nimi  ...    4.9
27                        Scopic  ...    4.9
28        Interactive Strategies  ...    4.9
29        Unleashed Technologies  ...    4.9
30                         Oyova  ...    4.9
31                  BrandExtract  ...    4.9
32             The Brick Factory  ...    4.9
33             My Web Programmer  ...    5.0
34                PureLogics LLC  ...    4.9
35                 Social Driver  ...    4.9
36            Calibrate Software  ...    4.9
37                    VisualFizz  ...    5.0
38               Camber Creative  ...    4.9
39               Susco Solutions  ...    4.9
40                  Lunarbyte.io  ...    5.0
41                    thoughtbot  ...    4.9
42         CR Software Solutions  ...    5.0
43             Solwey Consulting  ...    5.0
44                        Ambaum  ...    4.9
45          Pacific Codeline LLC  ...    5.0
46                          PERC  ...    5.0
47                   Beesoul LLC  ...    4.9
48                  Novalab Tech  ...    5.0
49                   Dragon Army  ...    5.0

[50 rows x 5 columns]
```

and the following data that is stored:

Process finished with exit code 0

```
Company_Name,Tagline,Location,Ticket_Price,Rating,Website_Name,URL
Hyperlink InfoSystem,"#1 Mobile App, Web, & Software Development Company","Jersey City, NJ","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Plego Technologies,Shaping the Future of Technology,"Downers Grove, IL","$10,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Azuro Digital,"Award-Winning Web Design, Development & SEO","New York, NY","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
App Makers USA,Top US Mobile & Web App Development Agency,"Los Angeles, CA","$10,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
ChopDawg.com,Dreams Delivered Since 2009. Let's Make It App'n!®,"Philadelphia, PA","$5,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Savas Labs,Designing and developing elegant web products.,"Raleigh, NC","$25,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
The Gnar Company,Solving Gnarly Software Problems. Faster.,"Boston, MA","$25,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Sunrise Integration,Enterprise Solutions & Ecommerce Apps,"Los Angeles, CA","$10,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Baytech Consulting,TRANSLATING YOUR VISION INTO SOFTWARE,"Irvine, CA","$25,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Inventive Works,Custom Software Product Development,"Manor, TX","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Utility,AWARD-WINNING MOBILE DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT AGENCY,"New York, NY","$50,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Busy Human,Making life more user-friendly,"Orem, UT","$1,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Rootstrap,Outcome-driven development. At any scale.,"Beverly Hills, CA","$50,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
micro1,"World-class software engineers, powered by AI","Los Angeles, CA","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Emergent Software,Your Full-Stack Technology Partner,"Saint Paul, MN","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
3 Media Web,Award-Winning Digital Experience Agency ,"Marlborough, MA","$50,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Beehive Software Inc.,Software reinvented,"Los Gatos, CA","$10,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Webstacks,"The website is a product, not a project.","San Diego, CA","$10,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Mutually Human,Custom Software Development and Design,"Ada, MI","$25,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
AnyforSoft,Amplify digital excellence with AnyforSoft,"Sarasota, FL","$50,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
NL Softworks,Website Design & Development Made to Convert,"Boston, MA","$5,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
OpenSource Technologies Inc.,Web & Mobile APP | Digital Marketing | Cloud,"Lansdale, PA","$25,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Twin Sun,Trustworthy partners that deliver results,"Nashville, TN","$25,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Marcel Digital,Changing the Idea of What an Agency Is And Can Be,"Chicago, IL","$5,000+",4.7,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Darwin,We create incredible digital experiences,"Reston, VA","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
SPARK Business Works,Award-winning custom software dev & web design,"Kalamazoo, MI","$5,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Nimi,"Bring your product ideas to life, to Grow Today.","Oakland, CA","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Scopic,"Your Cross-continental, Digital Innovation Partner","Rutland, MA","$5,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Interactive Strategies,"Full Service Digital Design, Dev & Marketing","Washington, DC","$100,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Unleashed Technologies,Unleash Your Potential®,"Ellicott City, MD","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Social Driver,Experience digital with us.,"Washington, DC","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Oyova,More Business For Your Business Is Our Business.™,"Jacksonville Beach, FL","$5,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
The Brick Factory,A DC-based digital agency.,"Washington, DC","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
My Web Programmer,→Top-Quality Custom Software & Web Development Co.,"Atlanta, GA","$1,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
PureLogics LLC,No Magic. Just Logic.,"New York, NY","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
BrandExtract,"We inspire people to create, transform, and grow.","Houston, TX","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Calibrate Software,We craft digital experiences that spark joy ,"Chicago, IL","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Camber Creative,Things worth building are worth building well.,"Orlando, FL","$25,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
VisualFizz,Impactful Marketing for Industry-Leading Brands,"Chicago, IL","$5,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Susco Solutions,Solve Together | Developing Intuitive Software,"Harvey, LA","$50,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Lunarbyte.io,Launching big ideas with startups & enterprises,"Seattle, WA","$25,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
CR Software Solutions,Innovative Digital Solutions For Your Business,"Canton, MI","$5,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Ambaum,Ambaum is your Shopify Plus Agency,"Burien, WA","$5,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Solwey Consulting,Custom software solutions to elevate your business,"Austin, TX","$10,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Pacific Codeline LLC,"Reliable, Experienced, 100% U.S. based.","San Clemente, CA","$1,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Novalab Tech,Your Trusted IT Partner,"San Francisco, CA","$10,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Dragon Army,A purpose-driven digital engagement company.,"Atlanta, GA","$25,000+",5.0,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
CodigoDelSur,Rockstar coders for rockstar companies,"Montevideo, Uruguay","$75,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Brainhub,Top 1.36% engineering team - onboarding in 10 days,"Gliwice, Poland","$50,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Curotec,Your digital product engineering department,"Philadelphia, PA","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
TekRevol,Creative Web | App | Software Development Company,"Houston, TX","$25,000+",4.8,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
XWP,Building a better web at enterprise scale,"New York, NY","$50,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
Five Jars,⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️ OUTSTANDING WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT,"Brooklyn, NY","$10,000+",4.9,Top Web Developers in the United States,https://clutch.co/us/web-developers
```

hmm - but wait: it does not work here - if we choose another base-url
https://clutch.co/il/web-developers

```
company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Timeout Exception occurred while waiting for company elements.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 74, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 767, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 503, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 114, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 677, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Process finished with exit code 1
```

well i think that this has to do with some exceptions

```
  import pandas as pd
Element not found while extracting company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Element not found while extracting company details.
Timeout Exception occurred while waiting for company elements.
```

well i think that there may be a whole couple of issues:

first of all there were some Element not found while extracting company details: This indicates that some elements were not found while extracting details for certain companies. This could be due to variations in the structure of the website or changes in the layout. I guess that we can handle this; thereofore we should include additional error handling or refine our XPath expressions.

during several  trials and attempts  also Timeout Exception occurred while waiting for company elements: This suggests that the script timed out while waiting for elements to load on the page.

last but not least i also had ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length: This error occurs because the arrays used to construct the DataFrame are of different lengths. This typically happens when one or more data points are not collected properly.

see below what code i used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import time

website = "https://clutch.co/il/it-services"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(website)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Function to handle page navigation
def navigate_to_next_page():
    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@class="page-item next"]/a[@class="page-link"]')
        np = next_page.get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(np)
        time.sleep(6)
        return True
    except:
        return False

company_names = []
taglines = []
locations = []
costs = []
ratings = []
websites = []

current_page = 1
last_page = 250

while current_page <= last_page:
    try:
        company_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'provider-info')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout Exception occurred while waiting for company elements.")
        break

    for company_element in company_elements:
        try:
            company_name = company_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "company_info").text
            company_names.append(company_name)

            tagline = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/p[@class="company_info__wrap tagline"]').text
            taglines.append(tagline)

            rating = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@class="rating sg-rating__number"]').text
            ratings.append(rating)

            location = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@class="locality"]').text
            locations.append(location)

            cost = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="list-item block_tag custom_popover"]').text
            costs.append(cost)

            # Extracting website URL
            website_element = company_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@class="website-link"]')
            website_url = website_element.get_attribute('href')
            websites.append(website_url)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Element not found while extracting company details.")
            continue

    current_page += 1

    if not navigate_to_next_page():
        break

driver.close()

# Ensure all arrays have the same length
min_length = min(len(company_names), len(taglines), len(locations), len(costs), len(ratings), len(websites))
company_names = company_names[:min_length]
taglines = taglines[:min_length]
locations = locations[:min_length]
costs = costs[:min_length]
ratings = ratings[:min_length]
websites = websites[:min_length]

data = {'Company_Name': company_names, 'Tagline': taglines, 'Location': locations, 'Ticket_Price': costs, 'Rating': ratings, 'Website': websites}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Check if DataFrame is empty
if not df.empty:
    df.to_csv('companies_test10.csv', index=False)
    print(df)
else:
    print("DataFrame is empty. No data to save.")
```